# python: creating histogram out of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and am learning how to do things the right way.

I have list of dictionaries `d`. Each dictionary represents users, and contains information like user_id, age, etc.  This list `d` can contain several dictionaries that represent the same user (but with slightly different information that does not matter for my purposes). I want to create histogram that shows how many users are in `d` with given age. How to do it in efficient way?

Edit:
I want to emphasise that I need to eliminate duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the classic approach to this problem would be to create a defaultdict:

```
import collections
histogram = collections.defaultdict(int)
```

Then iterate over the dictionaries in the list, and (using `d_list` instead of `d` as the name of the list of dictionaries),

```
for d in d_list:
    histogram[d['age']] += 1
```

But you included additional information that confuses me. You said multiple dicts could represent the same user. Do you want to eliminate those duplicates from the histogram? If that's your question, one approach would be to store the users in a dict of `user_records` using `(firstname, lastname)` tuples as keys. Then successive dictionaries representing the same user would smash one another and only one record per user would be preserved. Then iterate over the values in *that* dictionary (perhaps using `user_records.itervalues()`).

This general approach can be modified to use whatever values in each record best identifies unique users. If the `user_id` value is unique per user, then use that as the key instead of `(firstname, lastname)`. But your question suggested (to me) that the `user_id` wouldn't necessarily be the same for two users who are the same.

Once you have the eliminated duplicates, though, there's also a shortcut if you're using Python >= 2.7:

```
histogram = collections.Counter(d['age'] for d in user_records.itervalues())
```

Some example code... say we have a `record_list`:

```
>>> record_list
[{'lastname': 'Mann', 'age': 23, 'firstname': 'Joe'}, 
 {'lastname': 'Moore', 'age': 23, 'firstname': 'Alex'}, 
 {'lastname': 'Sault', 'age': 33, 'firstname': 'Marie'}, 
 {'lastname': 'Mann', 'age': 23, 'firstname': 'Joe'}]
>>> user_ages = dict(((d['firstname'], d['lastname']), d['age']) for d in record_list)
>>> user_ages
{('Joe', 'Mann'): 23, ('Alex', 'Moore'): 23, ('Marie', 'Sault'): 33}
```

As you can see, the `record_list` has a duplicate, but the `user_ages` dict doesn't. Now getting a count of ages is as simple as running the values through a `Counter`.

```
>>> collections.Counter(user_ages.itervalues())
Counter({23: 2, 33: 1})
```

The same thing can be done with any string or immutable object that can serve as a unique identifier of a particular user.

Comment: Could you expand this:"one approach would be to store the users in a dict of user_records using (firstname, lastname) tuples as keys. Then successive dictionaries representing the same user would smash one another and only one record per user would be preserved."

Comment: Note that you actually mean "Python >= 2.7". :)

Comment: Tuples of strings can be the key in a dictionary, and any given key can appear in a dictionary only once, so any duplicates will automatically be eliminated. I'll post some example code.

Comment: @capoluca He means that as you're putting users into the dict based on `(firstname, lastname)` keys, if there's more than one user with the same `(firstname, lastname)`, the later ones will override the earlier ones -- one way of eliminating duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group in lists all the dictionaries that have the same age and, after that, just calculate the length of those lists.

For example:

```
import itertools

l = [{'user_id': 1, 'age': 20},
     {'user_id': 2, 'age': 21},
     {'user_id': 3, 'age': 21},
     {'user_id': 4, 'age': 20},
     {'user_id': 5, 'age': 21},
     {'user_id': 6, 'age': 21},
     ]

def get_age(d):
    return d.get('age')

print [(age, len(list(group)))
       for age, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=get_age),
                                           key=get_age)]
```

Example output:

```
[(20, 2), (21, 5)]
```

Note: As pointed out by @Dougal, the list must be `sorted`. Otherwise `itertools.groupby` won't work as expected.

Comment: Note that `groupby` assumes the list is sorted by the relevant attribute, so you might have to do `itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=key_func), key=key_func)` where `key_func = lambda d: d['age']` (or `operator.itemgetter('age')`).

Comment: @Dougal You're completely right, I've updated my answer to make that clear. Also I've used a function instead of `operator.itemgetter` just in case to avoid `KeyError` exception. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Biggest frustration with groupby is that if it's a "global" groupby, you need to sort it first.  In your example if user_id:4 is changed to age 20 the result is "[(20, 1), (21, 2), (20, 1), (21, 2)]"  You would need to sort with the same key and then group by....get's to be an error-prone hassle.

Comment: @PhilCooper Yes, you're right. The answer has been updated to sort the list before using `itertools.groupby`. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @jcollado You could use `key_func = operator.methodcaller('get', 'age')` if you wanted, which is probably ever so slightly faster if you're doing it a lot. Really doesn't matter much though.

Comment: @Dougal Yes, that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score -2):

Trying to improve on @senderle's answer, hopefully I understood the problem better.

I assume the list contains dictionaries, where the keys are user IDs, and the data are objects which have the `age` property:

```
import collections
# Merge all dictionaries to one uid->age mapping (I'm sure there's a shorter way)
all_ages={}
for d1 in d:
   for uid,data in d1.iteritems():
       all_ages[uid]=data.age
# Count distinct users per age
histogram = collections.defaultdict(int)
for uid,age in all_ages.iteritems():
    histogram[age]+=1
```

Comment: does this line `for uid,data in d1` work if there is more mappings in dictionary

Comment: @capoluca ugoren's answer doesn't really make much sense. The line `for uid, data in d1` actually loops over the *keys* of `d1` and expects them to be 2-tuples, which is almost certainly not what you want to do. He might mean to loop over `d1.iteritems()`, but that data format is still wonky (though it makes sense for the `all_ages` loop). Also, Python doesn't have `++` (use `+= 1` instead). Senderle's answer is the same basic approach but actually makes sense.

Comment: @Dougal, I admit I got the syntax wrong (and didn't test it). Using `iteritems` for both iterations and `+=1` would fix it. The difference from senderle's answer is that I assume multiple users in each dictionary, while he assumes each dictionary is a user.