# Bar chart in pylab from a dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been reading up about this. And I have been unable to find how the data for a histogram is mapped. The way I understand it:

> A bar chart has a name and a value for each bin.

This seems to be a pretty simple and intuitive way to look at it. I searched around and found this question: [python: creating histogram out of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182516/python-creating-histogram-out-of-dictionary)

Which seemed to be a long way from what I am asking.

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'CLOVER':4,'SPADE':6,'DIAMOND':7,'HEART':2}
```

And I want to create a bar chart with this dictionary. The numbers will get bigger. But the number of bins will remain four.

I am doing this as a project. We are doing this kinda thing with different implementations and then checking how random(pseudo-random technically) each implementation is. And then we need to submit a report. Which we will construct together.

**please** help me with the code. And also some examples.

**specs**

```
Python 2.7
Tkinter 8.5
Pylab
```

Comment: It seems that you have got the histogram. What do you want?

Comment: I got the histogram from excel! I want to do this using pylab!

Comment: I wouldn't call that a histogram, but a bar chart. With that in mind, matplotlib has numerous [examples on bar charts](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) (just search for 'bar'), as well as an [extensive gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) with bar charts like yours.

Comment: @Evert: Thanks! It was a bar chart. Not a histogram!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have tried this and get a similiar histogram:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

d = {'CLOVER':4,'SPADE':6,'DIAMOND':7,'HEART':2}
X = np.arange(len(d))
pl.bar(X, d.values(), align='center', width=0.5)
pl.xticks(X, d.keys())
ymax = max(d.values()) + 1
pl.ylim(0, ymax)
pl.show()
```

It is not the same but similiar. If you want to modify the color, the width or etc, just refer to http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html.
[image]

Comment: exactly what I foudn out just some time before you answered! Thanks anyway!